# How to remove an element from a list in J by index?

Tags: j

The rather verbose fork I came up with is

```
({. , (>:@[ }. ]))
```

E.g.,

```
3 ({. , (>:@[ }. ])) 0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 4 5
```

Works great, but is there a more idiomatic way? What is the usual way to do this in J?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the J-way is to use a 3-level boxing:

```
(<<<5) { i.10
0 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9

(<<<1 3) { i.10
0 2 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

It's a small note in the [dictionary for `{`](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d520.htm):

> Note that the result in the very last dyadic example, that is, (<<<_1){m , is all except the last item.

and a bit more in [Learning J: Chapter 6 - Indexing: 6.2.5 Excluding Things](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/06.htm).

Comment: It's a very unusual syntax but definitely simpler than my way.

Comment: Your way is significantly more efficient for removing one item. It's probably the most efficient (at least between using `{`, `;.` or `/.`).

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to use the monadic and dyadic forms of `#` (Tally and Copy). This idiom of using Copy to remove an item is something that I use frequently.

The hook `(i. i.@#)` uses Tally (monadic #)  and monadic and dyadic `i.` (Integers and Index of) to generate the filter string:

```
   2 (i. i.@#) 'abcde'
1 1 0 1 1
```

which Copy (dyadic #) uses to omit the appropriate item.

```
   2 ((i. i.@#) # ]) 0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 3 4 5
   2 ((i. i.@#) # ]) 'abcde'
abde
```